# Exception to isotope filter items?

Tags: jquery, jquery-isotope

I use the following code to filter the content in my grid via my filter menu at http://themes.visualise.ca/visualise/

```
$('.menu-categories-navigation-container a').click(function(){
    var category = $(this).parent().attr('class');
    var filters = ('.'+category);
    $container.isotope({
        filter: filters,
    });
    return false;
});
```

But I would like the item with the .thelogo class to always remain visible since the logo and menu are part of my grid. So I thought I could maybe use some syntax in order to add some kind of exception? Maybe there is a better way?

Many thanks for your time and help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The filter property in isotope is a selector string, feel free to add compound selectors (just add .thelogo to it).

```
$('.menu-categories-navigation-container a').click(function(){
    $container.isotope({
        filter: '.thelogo, .' + $(this).parent().attr('class')
    });
    return false;
});
```

ps: this will fail if any item has more than one class. As the selector would think it was looking for a tag with the name of the second class, inside the first.

edit: forgot period

Comment: It doesn't work... The items are wordpress posts so yes it has more than one class on each of them.

Comment: ... but you still really helped me, thank you. See the answer below the filters variable is needed in order to include the dot in front of the class I guess.

Comment: Not really, you're just building up a string to use as a filter ".thelogo, .myClass". Your code does it too, it's just not necessary to declare those two vars to get the job done.  In regards to the multiple classes, what is the logic you want done here? Should the filter match ALL the classes of the clicked item? ANY one of them?

Comment: I totally get your point. I'm no experienced coder and to me, it helps to understand better what is the information we are using. ;-)

Comment: For sure, better to have your code make sense to YOU. And in all fairness when you make a string on-the-fly, like is done above, javascript DOES do just as much work as if you had declared a variable explicitly. So maybe a compromise would be using your method with a single line. The following would be exactly as efficient as my code, and might be as readable as yours.  var filters = '.thelogo, .' + $(this).parent().attr('class');

Answer (score 0):

The solution...

```
$('.menu-categories-navigation-container a').click(function(){
        var category = $(this).parent().attr('class');
        var filters = ('.'+category);
        $container.isotope({
            filter: '.thelogo, ' + filters,
        });
        return false;
});
```